# Python Peewee - Incorporating Peewee into an Existing Database with Tables that Lack an ID AUTO_INCREMENT field

Tags: python, mysql, raspberry-pi, peewee

I have a table that records temperature data, which as 1.2 million rows in it.

There is currently no primary key on it, although it has a candidate key.

Since Peewee requires all tables have an ID AUTO_INCREMENT column, should I simply add one to the table, or is there another way to go about this? I hesitate as doing this would require a stall in collecting temperature data, which wouldn't be detrimental to my statistical analysis, but would be impact-full nonetheless.

The MySQL server is on a Raspberry Pi so I would rather use Peewee as it is so lightweight and quick to prototype with.

Answer (score 0):

> Since Peewee requires all tables have an ID AUTO_INCREMENT column

That's not true. http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/models.html#non-integer-primary-keys-composite-keys-and-other-tricks

Comment: I should have stated that my candidate key is a composite key; sorry. Good to know for my other tables, however.

Comment: Oops -- didn't see the composite key documentation RIGHT UNDER the the primary key documentation..

Comment: This link has now moved and returns a 404. Could you update it to reference the new location please.